# How to speed up navmeshagent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use from `Navmeshagent` for move my `gameobjects`.
But they move very slowly.

i set navmeshagent.speed look like this :

```
Game_Controller.Database [source_index_i, source_index_j].Nute_M.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ().speed = 5000000000;
```

But they are still moving very slowly. Is there any other way to get things faster at Unity?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed property only dictates the maximum speed the agent will travel at. You're not seeing instantaneous results because you're not changing the acceleration property.

So do this:

```
Game_Controller.Database [source_index_i, source_index_j].Nute_M.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ().acceleration= 5000000000;
```

Then set your speed property however you need:

```
Game_Controller.Database [source_index_i, source_index_j].Nute_M.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ().speed = 10;
```

docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/class-NavMeshAgent.html